# C++ - SetWindowDisplayAffinity of a different window returns False

Tags: c++, winapi

Hi I have a C++ code that attempts to `SetWindowDisplayAffinity()` of a different window to `WDA_NONE`. However this function returns False indicating that it failed to set.

The target window is NodeJS Electron App that has `win.setContentProtection(true);`

Here is the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"electronapp");

    if (hwnd != NULL) {
        DWORD_PTR affinity = WDA_NONE;
        BOOL result = SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hwnd, affinity);

        if (result) {
            std::cout << "Window display affinity set to WDA_NONE successfully." << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            DWORD error = GetLastError();

            std::cerr << "Failed to set window display affinity. Error code: " << error << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Window not found." << std::endl;
    }

    cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

The `GetLastError()` function returns error code `5`. However, I've tried the following options:

- Disabling UAC
- Running as Administrator

Am I doing something wrong with this code? Or is it something else?

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity) states: "The window must belong to the current process."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows error code `5` is:

```
// Access is denied.
#define ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED              5L
```

The reason you get it is that [`SetWindowDisplayAffinity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity) requires that:

> The window must belong to the current process.

In your case the window belongs to a different process and therefore you cannot use `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` on it.

As for the reason the api is specified like that:
See this note in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity):

> This function and GetWindowDisplayAffinity are designed to support the window content protection feature that is new to
> Windows 7. This feature enables applications to **protect their own
> onscreen window content** from being captured or copied through a
> specific set of public operating system features and APIs.

*(emphasis is mine)*

And allowing you to override this setting from outside the process will make it more or less meaningless.